# Clipping shapefiles using point grid references

Tags: arcmap, clip

I imagine this is a simple answer but I'm struggling to find information on clipping a shapefile using grid references.

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1. My shapefile is a line feature of mean low water and I'm looking to clip from one point to another to produce a separate shapefile for use elsewhere.

[image: Print Screen]

The img shows the coast shp file displayed.

Comment: A screenshot would help. You could edit and [split the line manually](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-lines-manually.htm) by snapping to your points. Then select the split line and export as new shapefile.

Comment: This would work perfectly. I get error "Split point results in zero length polyline"

Comment: I dont know why you get that error. I suspect your polyline is not a single line. If so you would probably need to dissolve it then manual split. A better way would probably be to create a polygon feature class (or shapefile), digitize a polygon over the part of the river you want to export and then use [Clip](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/clip.htm) to extract the polyline.